# svn global-ignores to ignore contents of a specific directory, but no the directory itself

Tags: svn

I'm using SVN 1.7.5 from a Linux command line.

I have a directory that I do build tasks in called `CMakeBuild`. I like to keep this directory subverted as part of the repository since when I check out this project fresh on a new machine, the directory is there and ready to use.  However, I would like to ignore all the files and directories (recursively) within this directory (as it's a lot of generated CMake build stuff).

I'd like to do this globally rather than on a project-by-project basis (since I have a lot of projects with the same set-up).  So I'm trying not to do a recursive svn propedit.

Adding `CMakeBuild` to my `global-ignores` doesn't work, since the directory is already part of a repository (or many repositories, actually).

I've tried adding `CMakeBuild/*`  and also  `*/CMakeBuild/*`  as well, but this doesn't seem to help.

Is there a way to ignore all the files and directories in a specific directory, which itself belongs to a repository?

Regards,
Madeleine.

Comment: You're saying that you want to version this directory but keep it empty, so that when a build is started it's ready for use? Why couldn't you **not** version the directory (thus allowing you to ignore it) and make creating `CMakeBuild` (if it doesn't exist) the first step of the build script?

Comment: @alroc - yes, that is a means to solve the problem as I described.  It seems odd that SVN wouldn't provide support for something like I describe. But that's another thread. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Subversion **can** support it (in slightly different style) in 1.8+ only. But for Mercurial (for example) it's more easier task, BTW, and you can still use your old SVN-repo with hgsubversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can not** implement this in Subversion *by your style*

[Ignoring Unversioned Items](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) clearly states:

- Only file-patterns (globs) can be used, without path
- Ignored files must be defined as property of parent dir
- `svn:ignore` is not recursive

If CMake-artifacts have unique extensions, not used anymore in repository, you can *try* to use `global-ignores` runtime